# Passing a Boolean variable to an Array List with String's

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, boolean, abstract

Is it possible for me to hold all my private datatype within my abstract class so i can later use the stored information to be held within my array List (array list is in a different class). I have managed to store all Strings previously bur had no success with my Boolean value. I know that array lists are used to reference objects. Thanks

```
public abstract class Room
{
    private String roomID;
    private boolean ensuite;
    private String guest;
    private String nights;
    private String booked;

    public abstract room (String roomID boolean ensuite)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has this been copied exactly from your code? there is a `,` missing between `String roomId` and `boolean ensuite`. Also abstract is not needed in the method declaration.

Try this:

```
public abstract class Room
{
    private String roomID;
    private boolean ensuite;
    private String guest;
    private String nights;
    private String booked;

    public Room (String roomID, boolean ensuite)
    {
       this.roomID = roomID;
       this.ensuite = ensuite;
       //so on...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Room
{
    private String roomID;
    private boolean ensuite;
    // ...

    public Room(String roomID, boolean ensuite)
    {
      this.roomID = roomID;
      this.ensuite = ensuite;
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so by adding all the this. commands i should be able to call //return Room; that this will display all the information held correct? Thanks